# Deploying AAR on private BitBucket Repository

Tags: maven, android-studio, gradle, bitbucket, artifacts

I am trying to deploy artifacts to a private bitbucket repository. I was following this tutorial https://medium.com/@Mul0w/publish-with-gradle-on-bitbucket-1463236dc460 and also some other stack posts and managed to get to a decent point. However I am stuck post that.

I have added the following uploadArchives task to gradle.

```
uploadArchives {
configuration = configurations.archives
repositories.mavenDeployer {
    pom.groupId = GROUPID
    pom.artifactId = ARTIFACTID
    pom.version = VERSION
    configuration = configurations.deployerJar
    repository(url: "git:master://git@bitbucket.org:<Team Name>/<Repo Name>.git"){
        authentication(userName: <username>, password: <password>)
    }
    pom.project {
        name POM_NAME
        packaging POM_PACKAGING
        description POM_DESCRIPTION
        url POM_URL
        scm {
            url POM_SCM_URL
            connection POM_SCM_CONNECTION
            developerConnection POM_SCM_DEV_CONNECTION
        }
        licenses {
            license {
                name POM_LICENCE_NAME
                url POM_LICENCE_URL
                distribution POM_LICENCE_DIST
            }
        }
        developers {
            developer {
                id DEVELOPER_ID
                name DEVELOPER_NAME
                email DEVELOPER_EMAIL
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

When I run the command ./gradlew assembleRelease :module:uploadArchives --info

I get the following error

```
Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact "<group id>":"<artifact id>":aar:"<version number>" from/to remote (git:master://git@bitbucket.org:<team name>/<repo name>.git): Unable to put file
```

Why is gradle unable to transfer the artifact to the master branch of my repository? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The page you linked is stating that the branch should be `releases`, not `master`. As this way it works for me, I suggest keeping to it. So it should look like:

```
repository(url: "git:releases://git@bitbucket.org:<Team Name>/<Repo Name>.git")
```

Also you are trying to put into this Gradle script authentication data. 
I don't know if it would work, as I'm using SSH key for bitbucket account for git authentication.